# TestNG ant task fails on Mac OS X with error: No test suite found

Tags: macos, ant, testng

I have a Java project that I've been developing primarily in windows.  I have some unit tests that I've written in TestNG that I also run... I'm using TestNG version 5.14.1

My project compiles fine under OS X.  The TestNG tests also compile fine.. However when I try to execute the unit tests the task fails with the following error:

```
Omair-Inams-MacBook-Pro:PNServices omairkhawaja$ ant clean testng
...

compile-and-jar:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/omairkhawaja/source/my-project/common/server/PNServices/build/classes
    [javac] Compiling 131 source files to /Users/omairkhawaja/source/my-project/common/server/PNServices/build/classes
    [javac]                                                                                           
     [copy] Copying 7 files to /Users/omairkhawaja/source/my-project/common/server/PNServices/build/classes
      [jar] Building jar: /Users/omairkhawaja/source/my-project/common/server/PNServices/build/jars/PNServices.jar

compileTest:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/omairkhawaja/source/my-project/common/server/PNServices/build/test/classes
    [javac] /Users/omairkhawaja/source/my-project/common/server/PNServices/buildtools/build-test.xml:28: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 14 source files to /Users/omairkhawaja/source/my-project/common/server/PNServices/build/test/classes
    [javac] /Users/omairkhawaja/source/my-project/common/server/PNServices/src/test/java/com/corp/monitoring/my-project/service/discovery/PnDiscoveryServiceTest.java:234: warning: non-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument type for last parameter;
    [javac] cast to java.util.List<java.lang.Object> for a varargs call
    [javac] cast to java.util.List<java.lang.Object>[] for a non-varargs call and to suppress this warning
    [javac]         when(mdo.getList("ineligibleDevices")).thenReturn(ineligibleResultList, null);
    [javac]                                                                                 ^
    [javac] /Users/omairkhawaja/source/my-project/common/server/PNServices/src/test/java/com/corp/monitoring/my-project/service/discovery/PnDiscoveryServiceTest.java:252: warning: non-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument type for last parameter;
    [javac] cast to java.util.List<java.lang.Object> for a varargs call
    [javac] cast to java.util.List<java.lang.Object>[] for a non-varargs call and to suppress this warning
    [javac]         when(mdo.getList("ineligibleDevices")).thenReturn(null, null);
    [javac]                                                                 ^
    [javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    [javac] 2 warnings
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/omairkhawaja/source/my-project/common/server/PNServices/build/test/jar
      [jar] Building jar: /Users/omairkhawaja/source/my-project/common/server/PNServices/build/test/jar/agent-test.jar

testng:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/omairkhawaja/source/my-project/common/server/PNServices/build/testng
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/omairkhawaja/source/my-project/common/server/PNServices/build/coverage
   [testng] [TestNGAntTask] TESTNG PASSED @/var/folders/ft/p4_xg83109v465y_ktnrq29m0000gn/T/testng6488341970286082385 WHICH CONTAINS:
   [testng]   -usedefaultlisteners
   [testng]   false
   [testng]   -d
   [testng]   /Users/omairkhawaja/source/my-project/common/server/PNServices/build/testng
   [testng]   -groups
   [testng]   unit
   [testng]   -listener
   [testng]   org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter;org.testng.reporters.JUnitXMLReporter;org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter
   [testng]   -suitename
   [testng]   Ant suite
   [testng]   -testname
   [testng]   Ant test
   [testng]   /Users/omairkhawaja/source/my-project/common/server/PNServices/buildtools/suite.xml
   [testng] Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
   [testng] [ERROR]: No test suite found.  Nothing to run
   [testng] java.io.FileNotFoundException: test-output/testng.css (No such file or directory)
   [testng]     at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
   [testng]     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:194)
   [testng]     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:145)
   [testng]     at org.testng.internal.Utils.writeResourceToFile(Utils.java:618)
   [testng]     at org.testng.reporters.HtmlHelper.generateStylesheet(HtmlHelper.java:25)
   [testng]     at org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter.generateReport(SuiteHTMLReporter.java:49)
   [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:613)
   [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:999)
   [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:936)
   [testng] ERROR WHILE WRITING TO test-output/index.html
   [testng] java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
   [testng]     at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
   [testng]     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:883)
   [testng]     at org.testng.internal.Utils.writeFile(Utils.java:168)
   [testng]     at org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter.generateIndex(SuiteHTMLReporter.java:138)
   [testng]     at org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter.generateReport(SuiteHTMLReporter.java:75)
   [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:613)
   [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:999)
   [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:936)

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 13 seconds
Omair-Inams-MacBook-Pro:PNServices omairkhawaja$ 

Omair-Inams-MacBook-Pro:PNServices omairkhawaja$ pwd
/Users/omairkhawaja/source/my-project/common/server/PNServices

Omair-Inams-MacBook-Pro:PNServices omairkhawaja$ ls -l buildtools/ | grep suite
-rw-r--r--   1 omairkhawaja  staff   858  5 Apr 15:43 suite.xml
```

This is the testng target I'm using

```
<testng outputDir="${testng.report.dir}"
                workingDir="${test.resources.dir}"
                haltOnfailure="false"
                useDefaultListeners="false"
                listeners="org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter,org.testng.reporters.JUnitXMLReporter,org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter" dumpCommand="true"
                groups="unit" >
            <jvmarg value="-Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.properties" />
            <jvmarg value="-Dquest.debug=1" />
            <jvmarg value="-Xdebug"/>
            <jvmarg value="-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=7007"/>
            <sysproperty key="org.uncommons.reportng.title" value="PNServices Unit Tests"/>
            <classpath>
                <fileset refid="test-dependencies.fileset"/>
                <fileset dir="${fglam.devkit.home}">
                    <include name="**/*.jar"/>
                </fileset>
                <fileset dir="${fglcore.home}">
                    <include name="**/*.jar"/>
                </fileset>
                <fileset dir="${build.jars.dir}">
                    <include name="*.jar"/>
                </fileset>
                <fileset dir="${test.resources.dir}">
                    <include name="log4j.properties"/>
                </fileset>
                <fileset dir="${build.test.dir}/jar" includes="agent-test.jar" />
            </classpath>

            <xmlfileset dir="${basedir}/buildtools" includes="suite.xml"/>
        </testng>
```

This is my suite.xml file

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<!--Test suite name must not be changed as it is referenced in sonar-project.properties -->
<suite name="TestSuite" verbose="1" >
  <!-- Test MUST be named TEST-xxxx as Sonar requires this file naming format to be able to parse test results-->
  <test name="TEST-Unit">
      <packages>
          <package name="com.corp.monitoring.*" />
      </packages>

      <groups>
          <run>
            <exclude name="brokenTests"  />
            <include name="unit"  />
          </run>
        </groups>
  </test>
</suite>
```

As the command-line output in the beginning shows, my suite.xml file is located in the appropriate directory.. I'm not sure why TestNG runs successfully on windows but fails to run on OS X .. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue happened due to a ReportNG dependency being downloading using the maven ant task which also declares a dependency on an ancient TestNG version which was being picked up first in the classpath and causing the testng ant target to fail.

I ran into a similar issue on [Windows recently](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/testng-users/RbXv08IljLk/discussion) .. and after floundering for a while discovered what the issue was.. I was attempting importing the ReportNG dependency using the maven dependency ant task... and it was downloading an old version of TestNG... As noted by [Marcin Zajączkowski](http://solidsoft.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/better-looking-html-test-reports-for-testng-with-reportng-maven-guide/) to use reportNG in maven you need to exclude the transitive TestNG dependency..  I don't know if there's a synonymous fix possible when using the ant maven task.