# TestNG [Error] no test suite found. nothing to run

Tags: java, xml, selenium-webdriver, command, testng

I am 
Unable to run the testng test suite from command line I am using windows System

> TestNG [Error] no test suite found. nothing to run
>      had report ng listeners i have removed that fro my xml and i have removed those jars from library

I had referred this link 
[No Test suite found nothing to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075209/testng-ant-task-fails-on-mac-os-x-with-error-no-test-suite-found)

Commands using to run test suite

```
cd C:\Users\workspace\myproject

java -cp C:\Users\workspace\myproject\libs\*;C:\Users\workspace\myproject\bin org.testng.TestNG Analytics.xml

Analytics.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="BLR_Analytics" verbose="10" parallel="tests">

    <test name="Login" group-by-instances="true" verbose="3">
            <classes>
                <class name="analyticsMain.MainExecute" />

            </classes>
    </test>

</suite>
```

please help
Thanks,
Chaitanya

Answer (score 0):

```
When I started to run TestNG xml from console,I got lots of errors.I am not sure which error you are getting exactly,you try following one:

java -cp "C:\TestNG\testng.jar;C:\TestNG\jcommander.jar;H:\project\Test\src;c:\selenium-webdriver\selenium-java-2.45.0.jar;c:\selenium-webdriver\libs\*" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml

Add all these jars according to your settings.
```

Comment: i have tried adding jars still same issue, i am getting these errors Java File not found exception file  system cannot find the specified file AND TESTNG[ERROR] No test suite or test case to run

Comment: I think it is not able to find out path of your test class<class name="analyticsMain.MainExecute" />.In my case,build path is <project name>/src and including <class name="scripts.CheckTest" />.My project structure is <project name>/src/scripts/<test script file>.Please check this.